# Player de audio Android

Tags: android

Criei um player de musica ele esta funcionando 100% só que quando chega ao fim de uma musica ele não passa para a próxima da lista. Alguém sabe de uma solução para meu problema ? (Obs: as musicas tocadas e do sdcard).

```
public class Player extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

static MediaPlayer mp;
ArrayList<File> mySongs;
int position;
Uri u;

Thread updateSeekBar;

ImageButton btnVoltar, btnBackward, btnPrevious, btnNext, btnForward;

private ImageButton btnPlayPause;
private boolean isbtnPlayer = false;
SeekBar progressMusic;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

    btnVoltar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnVoltar);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPlayPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlayPause);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);       

    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(this);

    progressMusic = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progressMusic);
    updateSeekBar = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            int currentPosition = 0;
            while (currentPosition < totalDuration){
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                    currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    progressMusic.setProgress(currentPosition);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    };

    if(mp!=null){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();

    }

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    mySongs = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("songlist");
    position = b.getInt("pos", 0);

    u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
    mp.start();

    progressMusic.setMax(mp.getDuration());

    updateSeekBar.start();

    progressMusic.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }
    });

    btnVoltar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent home = new Intent(Player.this, Home.class);
            Player.this.startActivity(home);
            Player.this.finish();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.btnPlayPause:
            if(mp.isPlaying()){                 
                isbtnPlayer = true;
                btnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.player);
                mp.pause();
            }else{
                isbtnPlayer = true;
                btnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                mp.start();
            }break;

        case R.id.btnForward:
            mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition()+5000);
            break;

        case R.id.btnBackward:
            mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition()-5000);
            break;

        case R.id.btnNext:
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            position = (position+1) %mySongs.size();
            u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
            mp.start();
            progressMusic.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            break;

        case R.id.btnPrevious:
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            position = (position-1 < 0)? mySongs.size()-1: position-1;
            u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
            mp.start();
            progressMusic.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            break;

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara implemente o seguinte método que e da interface OnCompletionListener e dentro dele você deve chamar o MediaPlayer com a próxima música da lista.

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

}

Dentro do onCreate vc deve registrar o onCompletion adicionando o código abaixo: mp.setOnCompletionListener(this)

Comment: Na hora que eu adicionei o `mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);` no onCreate ele apresentou erro `The method setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (Player)`, dentro do `public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

}` eu passei o seguinte método `mp.stop();
  mp.release();
  position = (position+1) %mySongs.size();
  u = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
  mp.start();
  progressMusic.setMax(mp.getDuration());` para chamar a próxima musica, esta certo ?